# Safely Unmounting a USB

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive, usb

I'm new to Elementary. I'm also not used to non-debian Linuxes. How do I go about safely unmounting the USB which I used to install Elementary?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after install, just remove it when the pc goes off during reboot. In general you hit the eject button next to the usb sticks name in files. See screenshot
[image]

Comment: thank you so much. it's been a while since i've used linux, and the name of the USB stick was changed to ELEMENTARY-something during format, so i simply assumed it was part of the system files or something xD thank you again<33333